# Creating an average of a list of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

Simply question which I cannot seem to figure out myself.

I have a list of images called `img_list`, full of images with the same dimension and data type.
The individual images are loaded with `cv2.imread(path)` from the `opencv` library.

The goal is to create an average image the same as `cv2.addWeighted()` can create, only for an arbitrary amount(5-10000) of images.

My own attempt was the code below but I think it does not give equal weights to all the images (first two images are dominating the final output).

```
first_image = ""
average = ""
counter = 0
amount = 500
for image_og in img_list

    if counter > amount:break
    else:counter += 1
    f1 = 1/counter
    f2 = 1 - 1/counter

    image = copy.copy(image_og)

    if counter == 0:
        first_image = image

    if counter == 1:
        average = cv2.addWeighted(first_image, 0.5, img, 0.5, 0) 

    if counter > 1:
        average = cv2.addWeighted(average, f2 , img, f1, 0)
```

I also tried something like average = `np.uint8(np.mean(img_list))`, `average = np.uint8(sum(img_list)/amount)`, but that didn't work aswell.

Comment: Just add all the images one by one, and at the end divide by the count. The running sum should be a floating-point representation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Had the same idea but my execution must be wrong because my output image shows  "looping" of values (values above 255 are shown dark, even though there shouldn't be any values above 255). Could you post an answer if you know how to solve it?

Comment: That will not happen if you follow my advice: "The running sum should be a floating-point representation."

Comment: @CrisLuengo I obviously do not how to do that so how about an answer or more detailed comment instead of a quote? `for image in img_list:{average = average + image}; average = average / amount`(pseude code) does not work.

Comment: That should work if you initialize `average = np.zeros(img_list[0].shape)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you that worked. If you'd like you can post a short answer (first + last comment) and I will accept it.